# Prevent folding bike from unfolding

Tags: folding-bicycle

I bought a vintage folding bike recently. The problem is that when I fold it there is no mechanism to keep it that way.
I use a velcro strap but it's quite a hassle to put on when I'm trying to catch a bus.

Is there a better solution that you use or know of? The frame is steel and welding something on is also an option.

Comment: A picture of your bike will help us offer more accurate answers.

Comment: You might be able to make a velcro strap that stays attached and just needs doing up.  Or a strap with a plastic clip, again that stays attached.  Some sewing might be needed.  Pics would help

Answer (score 4):

I have a Brompton and although there is a mechanism to stop it from unfolding, the top part of the handlebar is not fixed very firmly so it can detach when I bump against something and then it swings outward.

I use a short bungee cord with hooks on both ends. It's a matter of seconds to put it around the handle bar and hook it into the pedal on the other side.

Without seeing your bike it's hard to know if this would work. Think through how the folding mechanism works, possibly there's only one part that you have to secure, and then find a bungee cord of precisely the correct length so you don't have to wrap it around in some complicated way but just quickly hook it into something.

Answer (score 3):

My (Dahon) folding bike came with a magnet positioned in two spots which connect when folded and easily releasing when you want to unfold. One on the axle of the front wheel, one on the axle of the rear wheel.

Look at your bike and see if there is a logical place for such a set of magnets and a way to place them.

Magnets can come with several different ways to attach them and you may have to select ones that fit your location. The ones on my bike have a bold on connection but I have also seen ones that come with a hole to feed a strap through or ones that will bend around a tube and can be glued on.

Answer (score 2):

Some folding bikes came with carrybags for this exact situation. If you have access to a sewing machine, then such things are straightforward to make and quite forgiving.

Light canvas would be ideal, but bagging the bike is probably more faffy than doing up the velcro strap.

Answer (score 1):

High quality folding bikes have a mechanism to prevent it from unfolding. For example, on Bromptons it's the seatpost not being extended that prevents it from unfolding.

However, if you want to push a Brompton forwards in folded position with the seatpost extended so that you can use the seat as the handle, then the mechanism no longer prevents it from unfolding. For this reason, I put a velcro strap around the frame tube of the Brompton. It can be used to retain it folded with seatpost extended.

I don't think you'll find a better solution than the velcro strap.